# Find value based on multiple conditions

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I have two excel files, one containing data of an event (STOPS_DATA) and one containing the amount of waste during that event (WASTE_DATA).

Sample data can be found in: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwNJFQtwUMCoalVwenhhb1hXcXc/view?usp=docslist_api.

In STOPS DATA the start time of a stop is in column A and the stop time is in column B. The type of waste I want is in Natte STOPAFVAL voor VERSTELLEN FS.

In WASTE DATA the starting time of the waste is mentioned in column A, the type of WASTE in column B and the amount of waste in C. (This amount I want to have returned).

I want to have after each stop in STOPS_DATA the amount of waste that is linked to it. Than I can use the other (not shown) data to calculate the performance of the factory

How do I approach this (still working on it myself but haven't found it yet).

Comment: It's really difficult to find mistake in a complex formula without the chance to try it. Please try to post a sample dataset with a simplified formula (without sheet names) to help us understanding your issue. Are you sure you should get result different from 0? Have you double checked date data types and are all the same?

Comment: The problem is the samples are all in dutch, so if that doesn't bother you I will post sample data

Comment: Can someone explain how to add sample data to the question?

Comment: use a file sharing service and post a link.

Comment: The Match() statement in your formula looks completely wrong syntax. Instead of a lookup range you have a complex formula with multiplications and various ranges. Are you using this as an array formula? Does that actually deliver a range for Match() to find a value in? Have you tried stepping through the formula with the Evaluate Formula tool? There you can see each part of the formula being evaluated in turn and you can see where errors come up.

Comment: I'm using the match described in [link](http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2012/07/12/check-multiple-criteria-with-excel-index-and-match/). Described under match with multiple criteria

Comment: I added sample data so you could try it.

Comment: I'm still not sure what the question actually is. You've explained the set up and also provided sample data (thank you), but what do you want to do? I'd suspect VBa will solve the issue quickly but I need to know what you want the expected result to be (and where)

Comment: If you need sum of Afval for 'Natte STOPAFVAL voor VERSTELLEN FS' for each time slot as per sheet STOPS_DATA then better to go for VBA. You can create variables, run thru the length of column, match the value and time slot and add up the Afval.

Comment: And also, if you want to reply to some one, use `@`, so if you wanted to reply to my comment, please add @Dave (and it will 'ping' me, alerting me that you have replied)

Comment: @Dave I want to have after each stop in STOPS_DATA the amount of waste that is linked to it. Than I can use the other (not shown) data to calculate the performance of the factory.

Comment: @pat2015 I don't have much experience with VBA so I'm trying to find a solution with build in functions of Excel and I will only turn to VBA as a last resort

Comment: So, would you want a 3rd column in the STOPS_DATA with this total? If so, would VBa work for you (I don't konw Excel well but I can do this with VBa, but it means you'd have to work with VBa for the future)

Comment: @Dave I've only written one macro in VBA, so I only know the basics.. I wouldn't mind trying with your solution, that I can learn more about VBA.

Comment: I assume the times do not matter, it's more about the day? So, for 1/2/15 the total answer would be 652m

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34302/discussion-between-michthan-and-dave).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer finally. This code finds all the waste for the stop specified.

> =INDEX(WASTE_DATA!$C$2:$C$1452;SMALL(IF((WASTE_DATA!$B$2:$B$1452=STOPS_DATA!$I$2);IF((WASTE_DATA!$A$2:$A$1452>(A2-TIME(1;0;0)));IF(WASTE_DATA!$A$2:$A$1452<(B2+TIME(1;0;0));ROW(WASTE_DATA!$B$2:$B$1452)-1;"");"");"");1))

And then press CSE. I use a nested IF function because AND doesn't work with arrays. I also substract an hour and add an hour to the dates just to be sure I don't miss a waste.